# Automatically generate Array(list) from single return function

Tags: java, arrays, function

This is more of a hypothetical question for slightly more readable code. Is there a more elegant way of doing something like this, apart from having another function to return the array? I've come across this code several times while writing JUnit Tests and it's just an eye sore. I have like 10 functions to generate specific types of random arrays and it's very cluttered.

```
public ObjectA getA()
{
    return new ObjectA("random", "stuff", "constructor");
}

public void doStuffWithA(ObjectA objs[])
{
    // do stuff with loop / array
}

public void main()
{
    ObjectA objs[] = new ObjectA[10];

    for (int x = 0; x < objs.length; x ++)
        objs[x] = getA();

    doStuffWithA(objs);
}
```

Perhaps something cleaner like:

```
doStuffWithA(toArray(getA(), 10));
```

But passing the actual function call doesn't seem possible.
Even this would be acceptable:

```
ObjectA objs[] = new ObjectA[10]{getA(), 10};
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Because as for now it's pretty "unclear what you're asking"... Do you want to initialize the array with some object or what?

Comment: Java 7, no "easy" way that I know of. You could of course create a java classes that gives you this functionality. But at java 7 there is little to none functional programming support. Java 8, on the other hand, may support such simplified statements once it is fully released.

Comment: @Eellee @LittleChild He wants a functional programming in Java. Instead of creating the array with a for-loop he would like to pass an argument to the array constructor, which in turn is called `x` times, populating the array.

Comment: @atomman Actually, using libraries like lambdaj for example, you can do that kind of thing with Java 7 (and beneath). Java 8 will allow such behavior without the need for such additional libraries.

Comment: @blalasaadri Hadn't heard about that lib, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something well known in functional programming; with basic Java (which is a imperative language) up to version 7, it is not possible. However there are ways to do this nevertheless.

The easiest path is probably learning how to use [lambdaj](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/). It will be a bit complicated but using that you'll be able to build a generator that you can pass to your function and that will create the objects as you need them.

A further possible way to do this is to write a generator class manually that will run your given function; the interface would look something like this:

```
public interface Generator<T> {
    T generate();
    T[] generateSeveral(int);
}
```

Then you can have an implementation such as this:

```
class ObjectAGenerator implements Generator<ObjectA> {
    public ObjectA generate() {
       return new ObjectA("random", "stuff", "constructor");
    }

    public ObjectA[] generateSeveral(int amount) {
        ObjectA[] result = new ObjectA[amount];
        for(int i=0; i<amount; i++) {
            result[i] = generate();
        }
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
doStuffWithA(new ObjectAGenerator().generateSeveral(10));
```

Comment: I think I will wait for Java 8 instead of getting a(nother) library into our project. I think this would be the best temporary compromise as our tests are getting quite in depth. Functions upon functions inside a Utils class isn't going to cut it pretty soon. Thanks.

Comment: Very understandable. You can test Java 8 with the early access version available at https://jdk8.java.net/download.html - using it for actual development is however not recommended yet as it will change before the final version comes out.

Comment: You could also remove the "boilerplate" `generateSeveral`, which will be fairly similar for all your generators. It would however require some use of reflection in order to create the correct type of array.

Answer (score -1):

Try Arrays.fill(Object[] a,Object val): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Randomness can be initialized in "getA". Each "getA" can return different object for each call, by initializing "java.util.Random", for example.

Comment: It seems like you are thinking of a similar solution to what @ByteCode posted, which results in an array filled with duplicate entries. Any "randomness" put into `getA()` wont help either as it is only invoked once.

Answer (score -1):

`Arrays.fill` will help you.

You can do like this

```
ObjectA objs[] = new ObjectA[10];       
Arrays.fill(objs, getA());

//just printing objects     
for (int x = 0; x < objs.length; x ++)
      System.out.println(objs[x]);
```

Comment: This will not create an array with unique objects as calling `getA()` ten times would. All the object withing `objs` would just be duplicates.

Comment: @atomman OP's not mentioned anything related to uniqueness in his question .

Comment: "specific types of random arrays" for unit testing, and his code. Therefore I feel it is fair to assume an array filled with duplicates is not the solution he is after. However, it would be nice to get OP's opinion on this mather.

Comment: Correct, duplicates would not help with our JUnit tests. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

Arrays.fill(ArrayOfObjects, ObjectA);